# std::minmax initializer_list<T> argument

Tags: c++, c++11, std, minmax

Maybe this question is a little bit *theoretic*, but I wonder what are the the design incentives behind defining `std::minmax` like this

```
template <class T>
pair<T,T> minmax (initializer_list<T> il);
```

Which means ,IMO, the passed object, `li` will be **copied** and each of its members must also be copy-constructible.

While, `std::min_element` (or for this matter `std::max_element`) is more "efficient" in the sense only the container iterators are being passed (no need to actually copy the entire container)

```
template <class ForwardIterator>
ForwardIterator min_element (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last);
```

EDIT - based on Joachim Pileborg comment, `initializer_list<T>` objects are not being copied, so I'm pinpointing my question - why `std::minmax` is constrained to such objects and not to arbitrary containers (which have "non-const" nature, so to speak)

Comment: From [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list): "Copying a `std::initializer_list` does not copy the underlying objects."

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Thx for your valuable comment, I've edited my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your updated question: `minmax` can also work with a general case of pair of iterators, it is called `minmax_element`. So `minmax` itself is just a convenience shorthand to be able to write compact things like this:

```
// define a, b, c here
int min, max;
std::tie(min, max) = std::minmax({a, b, c});
```

...instead of writing this:

```
// define a, b, c here
int min, max;
auto list = {a, b, c};
auto result = std::minmax_element(list.begin(), list.end());
min = *result.first;
max = *result.second;
```